# I am trying the command npm start but it gives error as follows.I am using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, npm-install

I want to use npm install command and npm start command but i got the following errror.My node version is -v0.10.25 and npm version is --3.9.5.How can i resolve the following error.Please help me how can i resolve this.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-app@0.0.0 start: `gulp serve.dev --color`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-app@0.0.0 start script 'gulp serve.dev --color'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp serve.dev --color
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/tannu/Desktop/ows-veraction-repo/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: where is the angular 2 code? Why do you use `v0.10.25`?

Comment: You may clone from https://github.com/rajkeshwarp/ows-veraction-repo.git

Comment: Then which version of node i should you.Please help me.

Comment: It works for me, I have node 6.2.1 installed with `nvm` https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Now I have following error.I have node version v6.2.2                                                                                                                  util.js:35
  var str = String(f).replace(formatRegExp, function(x) {
                      ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: try this : 
`rm -rf node_modules/ ` , then 
  `npm cache clean` , then 
  `npm install`

Comment: npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/tannu/local/bin/node" "/home/tannu/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-app@0.0.0 start: `gulp serve.dev --color`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-app@0.0.0 start script 'gulp serve.dev --color'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.

Comment: Thanks it work after rm -rf node_modules/ , then npm cache clean , then npm install

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to update your node to latest version (i.e. 6.2) after updating follow the following steps :

http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Now i installed node v6.2.2.But the error is RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.Could you help me please